# How to break the tie of SO and CS SE over an on-topic question for both?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Looking at computational-geometry tag wiki on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/computational-geometry/info) and [CS SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-geometry/info), I am not able to differentiate between their purposes. I find *theoretical* questions(asking for an algorithm) in both SO and CS SE under this tag. For example, I have asked a question [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/26237/15154) but later I realized that SO also permits *such* questions on computational geometry so now I am a bit confused as to how to decide where to post.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. You are proposing a *cross-site tag hierarchy*? What would that look like? Who would maintain it? And what would be the purpose? Why not just ask your question on whichever site you want, as long as it is on-topic?

Comment: @CodyGray "...Why not just ask your question on whichever site you want, as long as it is on-topic?". This is exactly my current problem in context of **computational-geometry** tag. I find my question to be _on topic_ for both SO and CS SE(based on their tag wikis and question asked by others there).

Comment: Okay, so...what's the question/issue to be discussed here?

Comment: I want to be sure on where to post my question. And to avoid such confusions only I thought of proposing organizing tags in form of hierarchy(I completely agree it will take very large effort).

Comment: @Pranav those are 2 different questions then, you should propose your feature in another question and make this question reflect your title about where to ask.  But before you propose your feature, I think tag hierarchical features have been proposed in the past, so you may want to do some research into previous discussions before proposing something new

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is not about code you've written, I'd say it's more on-topic on the Computer Science beta site where you posted it.

In cases where a question would seem to fit equally on two sites, post it on the site where it's more likely to get answered. You can look at the tag info pages on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/computational-geometry/topusers) and [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-geometry/topusers) to get a rough idea of that likelihood. (You also have to take into account the size of the communities, and how active the top answerers in your tags are.)